# Merge multiple DataFrames Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This might be considered as a duplicate of [a thorough explanation of various approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101), however I can't seem to find a solution to my problem there due to a higher number of Data Frames.

I have **multiple** Data Frames (more than 10), each differing in one column `VARX`. This is just a quick and oversimplified example:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'depth': [0.500000, 0.600000, 1.300000],
       'VAR1': [38.196202, 38.198002, 38.200001],
       'profile': ['profile_1', 'profile_1','profile_1']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'depth': [0.600000, 1.100000, 1.200000],
       'VAR2': [0.20440, 0.20442, 0.20446],
       'profile': ['profile_1', 'profile_1','profile_1']})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'depth': [1.200000, 1.300000, 1.400000],
       'VAR3': [15.1880, 15.1820, 15.1820],
       'profile': ['profile_1', 'profile_1','profile_1']})
```

Each `df` has same or different depths for the same profiles, so

I need to create a new DataFrame which would merge all separate ones, where the **key columns** for the operation are `depth` and `profile`, with **all** appearing depth values for each profile.

The `VARX` value should be therefore `NaN` where there is no depth measurement of that variable for that profile.

The result should be a thus a new, compressed DataFrame with all `VARX` as additional columns to the `depth` and `profile` ones, something like this:

```
name_profile    depth   VAR1        VAR2        VAR3
profile_1   0.500000    38.196202   NaN         NaN
profile_1   0.600000    38.198002   0.20440     NaN
profile_1   1.100000    NaN         0.20442     NaN
profile_1   1.200000    NaN         0.20446     15.1880
profile_1   1.300000    38.200001   NaN         15.1820
profile_1   1.400000    NaN         NaN         15.1820
```

Note that the actual number of profiles is much, much bigger.

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at the "Generalizing: mergeing multiple DataFrames" section, there is a `partial` solution explained there. If that was not helpful, please let me know how I might improve the post so it is clearer. Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Consider setting index on each data frame and then run the horizontal merge with `pd.concat`:

```
dfs = [df.set_index(['profile', 'depth']) for df in [df1, df2, df3]]

print(pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).reset_index())
#      profile  depth       VAR1     VAR2    VAR3
# 0  profile_1    0.5  38.198002      NaN     NaN
# 1  profile_1    0.6  38.198002  0.20440     NaN
# 2  profile_1    1.1        NaN  0.20442     NaN
# 3  profile_1    1.2        NaN  0.20446  15.188
# 4  profile_1    1.3  38.200001      NaN  15.182
# 5  profile_1    1.4        NaN      NaN  15.182
```

Answer (score 15):

A simple way is with a combination of [`functools.partial`/`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html).

Firstly `partial` allows to "freeze" some portion of a function’s arguments and/or keywords resulting in a new object with a simplified signature. Then with `reduce` we can apply cumulatively the new *partial object* to the items of iterable (list of dataframes here):

```
from functools import partial, reduce

dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
merge = partial(pd.merge, on=['depth', 'profile'], how='outer')
reduce(merge, dfs)

   depth       VAR1    profile     VAR2    VAR3
0    0.6  38.198002  profile_1  0.20440     NaN
1    0.6  38.198002  profile_1  0.20440     NaN
2    1.3  38.200001  profile_1      NaN  15.182
3    1.1        NaN  profile_1  0.20442     NaN
4    1.2        NaN  profile_1  0.20446  15.188
5    1.4        NaN  profile_1      NaN  15.182
```

Comment: Is it possible to also keep the column names? When I use this, the column names are gone.

Answer (score 2):

I would use append.

```
>>> df1.append(df2).append(df3).sort_values('depth')

        VAR1     VAR2    VAR3  depth    profile
0  38.196202      NaN     NaN    0.5  profile_1
1  38.198002      NaN     NaN    0.6  profile_1
0        NaN  0.20440     NaN    0.6  profile_1
1        NaN  0.20442     NaN    1.1  profile_1
2        NaN  0.20446     NaN    1.2  profile_1
0        NaN      NaN  15.188    1.2  profile_1
2  38.200001      NaN     NaN    1.3  profile_1
1        NaN      NaN  15.182    1.3  profile_1
2        NaN      NaN  15.182    1.4  profile_1
```

Obviously if you have a lot of dataframes, just make a list and loop through them.

Comment: thank you! @BlivetWidget, how do you sort it both by depth AND profile? each profile has a set of depths and each dataframe has a bunch of profiles?

Comment: @PEBKAC you can sort it by however many parameters you want, in whatever order you want.  .sort_values(['depth', 'profile']) or .sort_values(['profile', 'depth']).  You can check the help on df1.sort_values to learn how to change the sort order, to sort in place, and various other optional parameters.

Comment: @BlivetWidget, I'm sure this is a silly question, but I have 3 dataframes I need to join - does it matter if 1) they have no data in common and 2) their columns are not in the same order?  By 1, I mean that they have the same columns, but each row contains different data (this is 3 different infection types).  And, yes, I'm going to try it and see what happens.

Comment: @DataGirl that's not a problem, but as with anything else, only you can say if the result is what you wanted it to be.  Saying "join" in English is not very specific.  There are other functions like df.combine(), df.join(), and df.merge() that  are worth looking into if df.append() doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Why not concatenate all the Data Frames, melt, then reform them using your ids? There might be a more efficient way to do this, but this works.

```
df=pd.melt(pd.concat([df1,df2,df3]),id_vars=['profile','depth'])
df_pivot=df.pivot_table(index=['profile','depth'],columns='variable',values='value')
```

Where `df_pivot` will be

```
variable              VAR1     VAR2    VAR3
profile   depth                            
profile_1 0.5    38.196202      NaN     NaN
          0.6    38.198002  0.20440     NaN
          1.1          NaN  0.20442     NaN
          1.2          NaN  0.20446  15.188
          1.3    38.200001      NaN  15.182
          1.4          NaN      NaN  15.182
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
df = pd.merge(dfs[0], dfs[1], left_on=['depth','profile'], right_on=['depth','profile'], how='outer')
for d in dfs[2:]:
    df = pd.merge(df, d, left_on=['depth','profile'], right_on=['depth','profile'], how='outer')

   depth       VAR1    profile     VAR2    VAR3
0    0.5  38.196202  profile_1      NaN     NaN
1    0.6  38.198002  profile_1  0.20440     NaN
2    1.3  38.200001  profile_1      NaN  15.182
3    1.1        NaN  profile_1  0.20442     NaN
4    1.2        NaN  profile_1  0.20446  15.188
5    1.4        NaN  profile_1      NaN  15.182
```